# Как убрать в начале относительного url адреса (../)?

Tags: php, html, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите как убрать из относительного адреса две точки и слеш в начале при помощи регулярных выражений, используя команду preg_replace.

Comment: При текущей постановке вопроса ответом может быть разве "убрать три символа в начале"

Answer (score 1):

Перед регулярными надо сначала освоить обычные строковые операции. Например - функцию `substr()`, которая, собственно, и занимается вырезанием из строк.
Перед вырезанием можно проверить, надо ли вырезать, с помощью функции `strpos()`

Answer (score 0):

Если без регулярных выражений (и без знания php):

```
$trimmed = ltrim($text, "./");
```

Comment: `$trimmed = ltrim( "/home/user/path", "./" );` Ы?

Comment: @klopp результат же должен совпасть с `ltrim( "../home/user/path", "./" )`, нет?

Comment: Совпадёт (в том смысле, что первый слэш удалится), но в этом-то случае ничего удалять не надо.

Comment: @klopp никто точно не знает, что там топикастеру надо, а что - нет. может ему надо "типа отфильтровать"  пути, которые выходят за пределы текущей папки - и тогда ему надо и / и ../ вырезать.

Comment: А у него в вопросе-дубле было подробней рассказано что надо :)

Comment: @klopp в дубле тоже неоднозначно как понимать это "и". напрмер в фразе "trim убирает пробелы и табуляции в начале строки" вы будете ожидать что надо убрать именно " \t"? или все-таки и проблелы, и табуляции (и точки, и слеши)?